# Laravel 5 - How remove last where statement from query scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

i have a blade template and i want show count values from eloquent query with scope.

**In my Blade i have following:**

```
@foreach($searchQuery['item'] as $itm)
    {{ $searchItems['owners']->CountOwners($itm) }}
@endforeach
```

**My Model:**

```
Owners::all()
```

**My scope:**

```
    public function scopeCountOwners($query, $id){
    return $query->where('Item', $id)->count();
    }
```

My scope working fine and i get the item count, but only for the first owner in my foreach.
All other counts are '0'!

**My question is...
How i can remove the last where statement from my query?**

Or maybe you have a better solution :D

Comment: remove 'return' from scope

Comment: thanks for answer, but still same results :(

Comment: What exacly `$searchItems['owners']` or `$searchItems` is?

Comment: $searchItems['owners'] = Owners::where('Owner', $id)
sorry for edit...

Comment: Can You dumb `$searchQuery['item']` and paste result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collection methods (without scope).

Try this:

```
{{ $searchItems['owners']->where('Item', $itm)->count() }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still same result, this was my first solution ;)

dont forget... i have a foreach and want change where('Item', ???)

Comment: @Crni ,How is connect owners and items?

Comment: foreach loop shouldn't be a problem. Are You sure that other items has owners?

Comment: @Yurich
i have a repository where i get items from Owners

Comment: @D.Cichowski 
yep, foreach is the problem.
I think my query append every time where to query.

Comment: `$searchItems['owners']->where('Item', $itm)` will return Collection and DO NOT assign it to `$searchItems['owners']`. You are searching for error in wrong place and we can't find it eaither with so small piece of code.